# Как в WinForms сделать произвольную тень у форму?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как на C# в WinForms сделать произвольную тень у формы? Чтобы можно было менять радиус и прозрачность.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Тень от чего? Кнопки? Окна? Картинки?

Comment: Тень нужна для формы

Comment: А причём тут радиус? Или под «произвольной формой» вы имеете в виду закруглённые углы?

Answer (score 2):

Если хром (рамка у окна) системный, то тень тоже системная, и вы на неё никак не можете повлиять. В Win7 вы можете повлиять разве что на границы прозрачной аэро-области — с какого края как много она отнимает. На этом свобода действий заканчивается.

Если хром ваш, и вы рисуете рамку и системные кнопки самостоятельно, то и тень вы тоже можете нарисовать самостоятельно любыми доступными вам средствами: генерировать с помощью размытия, собирать из кусочков и т. п. В этом случае вы отвечаете за всё: и как обрабатывать нажатие на заголовок, и как растягивать окно, и как отображается тень, и как на всё это влияют пользовательские и системные настройки.

В обоих случаях вы можете воспользоваться `CS_DROPSHADOW` в `CreateParams`, чтобы насильно включить или отключить системную тень, но на её параметры мы повлиять не можете, и она вообще может не отобразиться, если пользователь отключил тени у окон.

Comment: Можно ж применить winapi для рисования в неклиентсой области окна. Ну и для установки её размеров тоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy Об этом я написал в варианте "если хром ваш". Или вы знаете способ рисовать тень за границами окна, где обычно располагается тень? Неклиентская область дотуда не распространяется, ЕМНИП.

Comment: Т. е. надо либо рисовать самому рамку вместе с тенью самому, либо иметь и то и другое системное? А дорисовать тень к системной рамке не выйдет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Варианта три: системная рамка и системная тень, своя рамка и системная тень, своя рамка и своя тень. Варианта системной рамки и своей тени нет. Впрочем, я не изучал вопрос глубоко, и не исключено, что я ошибаюсь. Я бы задался вопросом, зачем понадобилось игнорировать системные настройки и рисовать нестандартную тень. Это ненормально.